# Homeomorphism and Split Interval

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider the split interval $S(I)$: that's the space $I\times 2$ endowed with the topology generated by the lexicographic order. We can consider, analogously, the space $S(2^\omega)$ and delete their isolated points. How can I see that $S(2^\omega)\setminus\{isolated\, points\}$ is homeomorphic to $S(I)$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is $2^\omega$ here? The ordinal? The product of $\omega$ discrete $2$-point spaces? If the latter, what order are you imposing on it?

Comment: $2^\omega$ is the Cantor set endowed with the lexicographical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll construct the homeomorphism and leave the verification to you.

$2^\omega$ with the lexicographic order can be viewed as the middle-thirds Cantor $C$ set with the order that it inherits from $\Bbb R$. Let $E$ be the set of pseudo-endpoints of $C$, i.e., the set of points $x\in C$ that can be represented in the form

$$x=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{3^k}\;,$$

where $a_k\in\{0,2\}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$, and $a_n\in\{1,2\}$; for such $x$ let $\ell(x)=a_n$. The isolated points of $S(C)$ are the points $\langle x,i\rangle\in C\times 2$ such that either $\ell(x)=i=1$, or $\ell(x)=2$ and $i=0$. (For example, the points $\langle\frac13,0\rangle,\langle\frac13,1\rangle,\langle\frac23,0\rangle$, and $\langle\frac23,1\rangle$ are adjacent in sequence in $S(C)$, so the middle two are isolated.)

For $a\in\{0,2\}$ let $\hat a=\frac{a}2$. For

$$x=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{a_k}{3^k}\in C\;,$$

where each $a_k\in\{0,2\}$, let

$$\varphi(x)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\dfrac{\hat a_k}{2^k}\in I\;;$$

the map $\varphi:C\to I$ is a continuous surjection, it’s one-to-one on $C\setminus E$, and it’s two-to-one on $E$, identifying the two endpoints of each deleted middle third.

Let $X=\{x\in S(C):x\text{ is not isolated}\}$, and define a map

$$h:X\to S(I):\langle x,i\rangle\mapsto\langle\varphi(x),i\rangle\;;$$

then $h$ is a homeomorphism.